# PayPal API no longer showing the credit card form first with SetExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the following variables defined in my `SetExpressCheckout` API code:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard
```

Previously, this worked so that the shopper is first shown a form where he can enter his credit card details, followed by an option to log into his existing PayPal account. Since about a week however, everyone gets this screen:

[image]

Yes, I tested it from several machines, several countries, with cookies cleared, etc. And the sandbox is giving me the same issue.

Unfortunately, not all of our users are tech savvy and we've heard from several of them that they found no way to pay with credit card, even though the PayPal button to pay with a card is there - just not very visible because it's grey.

Is anyone experiencing the same thing lately? Have you found a way around it to display the credit card form first?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about this.

PayPal is split testing those checkout pages.  I've seen 3 different versions pop up lately.  The old/original one where the full form is displayed by default, this new page design/style with the button only, and I've also seen another new page design that does display the full form as well by default.

They are letting their split tests run their course, though, and in theory will choose the one that performs the best over all.